# Tag rename request: (synthetic-differential) to (synth-differential-geometry)

Tags: discussion, tag-management

At the moment there is the oddly named [`synthetic-differential`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthetic-differential) tag, which is being used for questions about synthetic differential geometry. I propose that this tag be renamed to `synthetic-diff-geometry`, perhaps with synonyms `synth-differential-geom`, `sdg`, and maybe `synthetic-differential`. (Apparently there is a 25 character limit on tag names...)

Comment: there is 25-character limit, AFAIR

Comment: The maximum length for a tag is 25 characters. The specific proposal is not feasible. Please, suggest an alternative that is shorter.

Comment: That explains the oddity...

Comment: @quid A recent [StackStatus tweet](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/656569338346868736) hinted at possibly variable length; but I don't know what sites and what changes were made.

Comment: @NormalHuman this is interesting, I was not aware of this. I just tried to add a 26 character tag on main, and it gives the usual warning. Thus, it seems on this site we are (still) at 25.

Answer (score 6):

To stay within the 25 character limit, we could rename it to `synthetic-diff-geo`, possibly with synonyms such as `synthetic-differential` and `sdg`.
(If someone starts typing "synthetic differential geometry" into the tag bar, we want them to find the tag. So the name should start with "synthetic" at least.)