# Expanding abbreviated tag names

Tags: discussion, tagging, character-limit

As the character limit for tag names [was raised to 35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490), we can now replace some awkwardly abbreviated tag names (like [geometric-invariant-theor](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25323/fixing-the-newly-created-geometric-invariant-theor-tag)) with their fully spelled out names.

I've already done that for a few tags:

- [moment-generating-functns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moment-generating-functns)
- [geometric-invariant-theor](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-invariant-theor)
- [pseudo-differential-opera](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pseudo-differential-opera)
- [unique-factorization-dom](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unique-factorization-dom)
- [linear-diophantine-eqns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-diophantine-eqns)
- [delay-differential-eqns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/delay-differential-eqns)
- [combinatorial-group-th](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combinatorial-group-th)
- [combi-number-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combi-number-theory)

are now synonyms of the full versions.

If you come across further instances of [awkward-abbrvtns](/questions/tagged/awkward-abbrvtns), please drop a note here so that it can be fixed without bumping dozens of posts.

Comment: Should related threads be closed as a duplicate of this one?

Comment: A similar expansion effort is taking place at MO, https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/862/help-cleanup-tags, where it has been suggested that a search for length-25 tags would be a good way to spot awkward abbreviations.

Comment: @GerryMyerson In fact, the same thing happen here, although it was [discussed in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20352/conversation/character-limit-for-tag-names-increased-to-35). As you can see in the transcript, Daniel started with [length 25 tags](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/708452/tags-with-given-length-of-name?length=25) and then he also went through tags with [length >=20](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/708458/tags-with-tagname-of-lenght-at-least?length=20).

Comment: @Daniel Fischer, any updates regarding the list of short tags? As far as I can see, no actions have been taken for that list.

Comment: @wythagoras I wasn't sure what to do with [tag:svd], [tag:pde] and [tag:sde] (these are pretty standard abbreviations), so I waited to see whether some opinions on those would be posted. And then - oh look, a squirrel - I sort of got distracted from the whole thing.

Answer (score 11):

I also went trough the list of extremely short tags (using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/708452/tags-with-given-length-of-name?length=3)).

- [svd](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svd) can be expanded into [singular-value-decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/singular-value-decomposition) (created synonym)
- [lft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lft) can be expanded into [linear-fractional-transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-fractional-transformation) (renamed without synonym)
- [sos](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sos) can be expanded into [sum-of-squares-method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sum-of-squares-method) (renamed without synonym)
- [rbf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rbf) can be expanded into [radial-basis-functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radial-basis-functions) (renamed without synonym)
- [pde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pde) can be expanded into [partial-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/partial-differential-equations) (preserved but created synonym)
- [sde](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sde) can be expanded into [stochastic-differential-equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stochastic-differential-equations) (renamed but kept synonym)
- [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) can be expanded into [topological-quantum-field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theory) (synonym exists, preserved)
- [lmis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lmis) can be expanded into [linear-matrix-inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linear-matrix-inequality) (renamed with synonym)
- [rkhs](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rkhs) can be expanded into [reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces) (merged with synonym)
- [socp](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socp) can be expanded into [second-order-cone-programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/second-order-cone-programming) (renamed with synonym)
- [dglas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dglas) can be expanded into [differential-graded-lie-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-graded-lie-algebras) (renamed to [dg-lie-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dg-lie-algebras))
- [dg-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dg-algebras) can be expanded into [differential-graded-algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/differential-graded-algebras) (kept but  synonym exists)

Since I'm not sure how much the abbreviated version is used in general, it is not entirely clear which one  of these tags should be the master tag and which one the synonym, and whether the synonym is even needed. If some tag needs more discussion, please expand it to a new answer.

Comment: I think that pde should stay (but it can't hurt do have synonyms between pde and partial-differential-equations). Maybe the same is true for sde and svd, since both are very common abbreviations. The others I agree with for sure.

Comment: I agree that pde and sde should stay. I mainly included them for completeness, and maybe for the reverse synonym (i.e. having pde as master tag and partial-differential-equations as the synonym).

Comment: Another alternative for (lft) was suggested in [Tag management 2017](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25694#26882).

Comment: I did something about all proposals. I am not sure I chose the best option each time but it's easy to change. Feel free to comment obviously. Maybe it's best to take the changed version as a new base line and to propose changes in the usual ways (eg, post in tag management thread)

Answer (score 5):

The [divisors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors) is for divisors in algebraic geometry.

There have been discussions about this in the Tag management threads earlier:

[Tag management 2015](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19037/tag-management-2015/21538#21538) and 
[Tag management 2016](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/tag-management-2016/24834)

Among the options is expanding the tag name to [divisors-algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors-algebraic-geometry).

Comment: I doubt we'll find a better name than [tag:divisors-algebraic-geometry], so I'll probably do that. But first somebody needs to check whether any mistagged questions about divisibility are in there. I won't do that before dinner.

Comment: @DanielFischer I see that now [there is a synonym](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/divisors-algebraic-geometry/synonyms) (divisors) $\to$ (divisors-algebraic-geometry). Would removing (divisors) be better? (I mean, it is possible that somebody will think that they are adding the tag (divisors). And if they are not careful, they will not notice that the tag was changed after it was added. I agree that the likelihood of incorrect tagging is smaller than before, but I think that it might still happen.)

Answer (score 5):

The [probability-limit-theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-limit-theorem) can be expanded to [probability-limit-theorems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/probability-limit-theorems).

See this answer: [Tag cleanup 2014](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12485/tag-cleanup-2014/16883#16883)

Comment: Also done that.

Answer (score 4):

It has been suggested that [synthetic-differential](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthetic-differential) is expanded to [synthetic-differential-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synthetic-differential-geometry):

[Tag rename request: (synthetic-differential) to (synth-differential-geometry)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21822/tag-rename-request-synthetic-differential-to-synth-differential-geometry)

Comment: Tag name has been expanded.